# Capturar ID en un table php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Es posible capturar un ID en un table?
Tengo  un table en el cual esta un curso registrado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la ultima Columna **ACCION** donde esta el ojito quiero que me despliegue otra lista la cual me da todas las asistencias de dicho curso, esas asistencias estan en otra tabla

Pensaba en quiza capturarlo con un $_GET asi como hago en el boton de editar pero no se como se deberia de hacer en este caso

El codigo que utilizo para $_GET en el boton editar es este

```
if  (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM cda_informacion WHERE id=$id";
   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     $codigo_zona = $row['codigo_zona'];
     $codigo_sector = $row['codigo_sector'];
     $nombre_lider = $row['nombre_lider'];
     $fecha_inicio = $row['fecha_inicio'];
     $dia_reunion = $row['dia_reunion'];
     $direccion = $row['direccion'];
     $modalidad = $row['modalidad'];
     $hora = $row['hora'];
     $anfitrion = $row['anfitrion'];
     $asistente = $row['asistente'];
   }
 }
```

alguien ayuda

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta ¿Te refieres seleccionar el curso y mostrar las asistencias de dicho curso? en tu codigo de php ya estas capturando el id de dicho curso solo debes de modificar tu consulta supongo que debes tener otra tabla de asistencias referenciada a los cursos

Comment: Asi es, pero como lo hago en un <table>,, ya que en un form lo tengo asi
** <form action="CDA_edit.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="POST" >  **

Pero no se como mandar a llamar lo mismo en un table, no se si sera igual?

Comment: Añade el codigo completo en tu pregunta para poderte ayudar por favor

Comment: @MarcoTulio el comentario que haces de que tienes un form en la tabla no le veo mucho el caso, sería agregar un link así `<a href="CDA_edit.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">Editar</a>` y al parecen en base a esto te estas confundiendo de como hacerlo hacia una tabla